# Fixed Step Size in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I'm trying to solve this system with a fixed step size of 0.1,

```
ecuA = {
   sA'[t] == -Piecewise[{
       {f[rL, r, \[Gamma], sA[t], iAt[t]], 0 <= t <= 1},
       {fL[rL, \[Gamma], sA[t], iAt[t]], 1 < t <= 11}}],
   eA1'[t] == Piecewise[{
       {f[rL, r, \[Gamma], sA[t], iAt[t]], 0 <= t <= 1},
       {fL[rL, \[Gamma], sA[t], iAt[t]], 1 < t <= 7}}] - 
     2 \[Sigma] eA1[t],
   eA2'[t] == 2 \[Sigma] (eA1[t] - eA2[t]),
   iA1'[t] == 2 \[Sigma] eA2[t] - 2 \[Gamma] iA1[t],
   iA2'[t] == 2 \[Gamma] (iA1[t] - iA2[t]),
   rA'[t] == 2 \[Gamma] iA2[t],
   iAt[t] == iA1[t] + iA2[t],
   sA[0] == 100,
   eA1[0] == 0,
   eA2[0] == 0,
   iA1[0] == 1,
   iA2[0] == 0,
   rA[0] == 0,
   iAt[0] == 1};
```

when:

```
fL[rL_, \[Gamma]_, sA_, iA_] := rL \[Gamma] sA iA;
fW[rL_, rW_, \[Gamma]_, sA_, iA_] := rL + (rW - rL) \[Gamma] sA iA;
f[rL_, r_, \[Gamma]_, sA_, iA_] := rL + (r - rL) \[Gamma] sA iA;
```

Therefore, I used the next code:

```
sol = NDSolve[ecuA,
   {sA[t], eA1[t], eA2[t], iA1[t], iA2[t], rA[t], iAt[t]},
   {t, 0, 7}, StartingStepSize -> 1/10, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}];
```

However, I got an error (`NDSolve::nodae`):

[image]

So, why is this error happening?, How can I solve the system for a fixed step size of 0.1?

Comment: Your system is a differential-algebraic system, and you have to use the IDA solver, which is not fixed-step.  You could differentiate the algebraic equation and supply initial conditions for the algebraic variables to derive an equivalent ODE system.  Then you could use a fixed-step method.

Comment: parameters `rL, \[Sigma], \[Gamma]` aren't defined!

Comment: Curious why you want to used a fixed-step method, when much better methods are available?